# When I was checking the 'Account Name' field in Contact Object it is appearing as a 'Lookup(Account)

Tags: opportunity

When I was checking the `Account Name` field in Contact Object it is appearing as a `Lookup(Account)`  account is parent and contact is child i know those relation ships and behavior
 parent to child query 
ex: `account ac =[select id,name ,(select id,anme from contacts) from account];`
same like 
contact is parent and `Opportunity` child [image]but query from different

```
List<contact> consobj=[SELECT id,firstname,(SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRoles) ,lastname FROM contact ];
```

what is difference between `Account`/`Contact` and `Contact`/`Opportunity`

Answer (score 4):

The difference basically lies in how both account and opportunities are related to each other.

> Salesforce allows to capture only once account per contact object,
>   which seems legit, its a rare possibilty that a contact is related to
>   multiple Accounts. So we have one-to-many relationship between Account
>   and Contact, viz. one Account can have multiple contacts, but one
>   contact can be associated with only one Account.
>
> Now coming to, opportunityContactRole. It is a junction object between
>   Opportunity and Contact. There is a many-to-many relationship between
>   Opportunity and Contact, through a junction object  alled
>   OpportunityContactRole. In an opportunity, you may add many
>   opportunity contact roles and reverse is also true

Hope this clarifies your query.